# How do I access my dedicated server?

Tags: centos, ftp

I just purchased dedicated hosting for the first time and had CentOS installed on the server. The server engineer sent me an email with the IP address, username, and password. I tried going to the IP address, but I was not given a log-in box. I'm obviously missing something.

Please let me know how I can log on. I'm trying to set up a Magento ecommerce store on the website, so I'll need access to FTP and phpMyAdmin. Any advice on steps I should be taking with my new dedicated hosting would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: Not to be rude or anything but does the service provider have a guide to this? And/Or could they have mis-configured the server?

Comment: Robert - They don't. Since they sell server administration as a service, I don't think they want it to be too easy for you to set it up. I've found some guides on GoDaddy that I'm trying to follow. 

This one to be specific: http://help.godaddy.com/article/6012?locale=en#access

Comment: Have you contacted the provider and asked them to verify if their settings are in fact the ones you were sent? It's wouldn't be the first time such an error was made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nick - have you used Linux before? If so, then you should be familiar with logging-in via `ssh` to the ip address given to you, along with the username and password.

If not, I'd highly recommend finding someone you know who's experienced with the platform and learning from them!

A quick SSH howto: http://kimmo.suominen.com/docs/ssh/

To install ftp - `yum install vsftpd` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vsftpd)

as for phpMyAdmin: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/docs.php - `yum install phpmyadmin`

The [vsftpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/F0HpYF56) I use.

Comment: Warren, I've dual-booted Ubuntu 10 for a short period of time on my laptop, but that's the extent of my experience. I don't have any knowledge of ssh unfortunately, but I'm looking into it now. If you have any good resources you can provide, it'd be appreciated.

EDIT: Also - I don't know anyone who has experience with Linux, so you guys and google are my only hope! :)

Comment: Got SSH log-on working, now all I have to do is figure out how to do everything else haha. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Sorry to take your check mark away - I just want to get some more input from the community on other parts of my question like how to set up FTP and phpMyAdmin or any other things I should be doing with my new server.

Comment: @Nick - generally it's good form to ask one question per, uh, question (you specifically only asked for help accessing the server, your comments about phpmyadmin and magneto were just that - comments, not questions). So if this question was about how to access the server, then you should keep this question as answered and then ask a different question for how to install php etc. You'll probably find that each question has been asked here before anyway.

Comment: @Nick - Give @warren the check. He answered your question. This isn't a discussion forum, if you have a second question, ask a separate second question.

Comment: Sorry guys. I'm new to stack exchange. I was under the impression that if I gave a check mark, it would take my question off of the active list and therefore no more people would see my question. When I asked for access to my server, it was more of a question of "How do I start installing Magento and working on my website." My unfamiliarity with dedicated servers led me to believe that once I signed in I'd be good to go, but I now realize there is a lot more involved. I'll keep your comments in mind in the future. And @warren - thanks for all the excellent help! :)

Comment: @Nick - no worries, it's a new system that takes some getting used to. Feel free to ask as many questions as you like though, just as long as each one is its own question :)

Answer (score 1):

Most FTP clients (such as Filezilla) support SFTP - just type in the server's IP address, 'root' for the username, and your root password, then change the port to 22. This will give you full access to all your files on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried FTPing to the IP address that you were given, using the username and password that were provided to you?

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work.

Comment: this might be that FTP is not installed or the firewall from the hosting provider is by default restricting port 21, give them a call and have them open it to your server from X network to Y server (x=your network) (y=the servers ip)

Managed hosting might be something you will wont to look for later on.

Answer (score 0):

If they just gave you a dedicated server with a base install of CentOS, it sounds like there is going to be a good amount of configuration required before you're able to use it as a webserver. I'd check with the provider to see what features they installed and what they allow through their firewall.